# EWS reply mail with original body

Tags: c#, email, exchangewebservices

When i want to reply a mail via EWS like below, if I retrieve a email body in html format like below. How can I put some reply text conveniently, just at the top of the original message?

Although I can parse the html, I am wondering there is any smart way doing it. thank you

```
EmailMessage mesg = email.CreateReply(false).Save();
mesg.Load();
MessageBody lvMessageBody = mesg.Body;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this by setting the `BodyPrefix` property on the reply. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn617213(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: thank you. I missed BodyPrefix() funcion. It exactly solves it.